# Выборка разделов инфоблока только с активными элементами внутри

Tags: php, битрикс

Надо получить список разделов, в которых будут активные элементы в заданном годовом диапазоне. Работаю с компонентом `bitrix:catalog.section.list`. Года приходят параметром `json_decode(urldecode($_GET["PARAMS"]), true);`

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "активные элементы в заданном годовом диапазоне". Год из даты создания элемента? Или это какое-то свойство "Год" инфоблока?

Answer (score 1):

С помощью метода `CIBlockElement::GetList` получаете массив содержащий нужные Вам `SECTION_ID`. Затем этот массив скармливаете параметру `"SECTION_ID"` компонента `catalog.section.list'.

Пример работы с `CIBlockElement::GetList` можете посмотреть в [документации](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getlist.php).
Примерный код для Вас можно набросать если понять что такое годовой диапазон элемента, это дата создания, дата изменения, свойство инфоблока.